# Bootstrap 3 How to Prevent Active Tab from Closing on Click

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using bootstrap 3 tabs, the default behavior when an active tab is clicked is that tab (and the associated tab pane) are both closed, leaving no tabs selected.

What I would like instead is for nothing to happen when an active tab is clicked. I simply want that active tab to stay active and don't even want it to be clickable. How do I over-ride the default bootstrap behavior to make this possible site-wide?

I have tried doing something like this thinking I could catch the clicks and over-ride the behavior but this didn't work.

```
$('.nav-tabs.active').click(function(event) {
  //Put over-ride code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The default BS3 result I get is the `.active` tab does not do anything when clicked.

I think this is the result you are describing?

See default example below taken from [w3schools.com/bootstrap](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_tabs_dynamic&stacked=h)

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Are you sure you are using all the correct html attributes like `data-toggle="tab"` and tab content `id`s linked to `.nav-tabs a` attribute href value?

Comment: Thank you! It turns out some other JS (Jquery UI) is over-riding this default behavior and causing this issue. So I'm not sure how to fix this other than ditching JQuery UI which we use for a couple other things. Seems like JQuery UI and bootstrap don't play well together.

Comment: @TedJohnson I've added jQuery UI 1.13 to my code in my answer and it is still working fine. Are you sure jQuery UI is the issue? Have you tried pasting my code into your project to see if you still get the same issue? Could be a slight markup error in your code which is causing the problem.